# ActiveRecord.joins adding unwanted sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

I am new to rails so forgive the question if its silly :S

I am using Spree as my e-commerce platform of choice.

In the Rails Console I run:

```
Spree::Product.joins(:product_properties, :taxons, :variants).limit(10)
```

this returns the sql:

```
SELECT `spree_products`.* FROM `spree_products` INNER JOIN `spree_product_properties` ON `spree_product_properties`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` INNER JOIN `spree_products_taxons` ON `spree_products_taxons`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` INNER JOIN `spree_taxons` ON `spree_taxons`.`id` = `spree_products_taxons`.`taxon_id` INNER JOIN `spree_variants` ON `spree_variants`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` AND `spree_variants`.is_master = 0 AND `spree_variants`.deleted_at IS NULL LIMIT 10
```

However, I need the sql to set the values

```
 `spree_variants`.is_master = 1 AND `spree_variants`.deleted_at IS NOT NULL
```

Does an one know how to do this? I have tried

```
Spree::Product.joins(:product_properties, :taxons, :variants).limit(10).where("`spree_variants`.is_master = 1 AND `spree_variants`.deleted_at IS NOT NULL")
```

but this doesnt work and generates the following sql

```
SELECT `spree_products`.* FROM `spree_products` INNER JOIN `spree_product_properties` ON `spree_product_properties`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` INNER JOIN `spree_products_taxons` ON `spree_products_taxons`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` INNER JOIN `spree_taxons` ON `spree_taxons`.`id` = `spree_products_taxons`.`taxon_id` INNER JOIN `spree_variants` ON `spree_variants`.`product_id` = `spree_products`.`id` AND `spree_variants`.is_master = 0 AND `spree_variants`.deleted_at IS NULL WHERE (`spree_variants`.is_master = 1 AND `spree_variants`.deleted_at IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll save a lot of time by using [squeel](http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/) gem. It uses blocks extensively and allows you to write (among other features) queries like this on pure Ruby:

```
.where{(spree_variants.is_master == 1) & (spree_variants.deleted_at != nil)}
```

Note the using of square brackets and absence of symbols.

To use these features just add this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'squeel'
```

and run `bundle install`.

Comment: hmm, whilst this solution may work I would rather see if there is another way using active record as not sure what effect this would have throught out the rest of the app where the data is passed?

Comment: This gem is very popular. It has a great history. Even if it's "plugged" you can still write you app in a old way (`where(id: 5)`). So it's compatible with your code.

Comment: Ok I managed to solve the initial issue by changing the joins. but now the where clause adds and extra AND ( before my query :S